# Android Tween does not start

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am trying to get a very simple animation to work. Here is the code snippet pertaining to the problem :

```
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_view_image);

        WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;             
        windowManager.addView(imageView, params);

        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 200);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                Log.i("start", "called");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Log.i("end", "called");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                Log.i("repeat", "called");
            }
        });
        imageView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Not only is the animation not starting, none of the Logs are being logged in Logcat. Which means, the TranslateAnimation **animation** is not starting at all. I don't understand why this is happening. Please help.

Comment: Try setting up animation duration before starting it, for example : animation.setDuration(100);

Comment: or  `imageView.animate().translationY(200f).setDuration(1000);`

Comment: @d.gjinovci What you proposed works, but the question persists that why does Tween animation not work?